# Keep same columns height with onclick event that change the clicked container height

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I'm not able to solve this particular problem. What i need to do is to have all the columns on my layout with the same height, the problem -as usually- is that all of them can have different information which means all of them would have different heights if i don't use a min-height.

That's actually easy to solve with either min-height or the MatchHeight Jquery plugin. The problem is that when the user click on the "más información" link at the end of each box the container will expand their height and show more information, this behaviour causes the MatchHeight plugin to work in a different way and break the layout. Any help will be REALLY appreciated.

A flexbox or jquery solution would work for me.

[Here's a Pencode where you can check the problem](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRBqNP)

Here's the HTML:

```
<section class="content col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1">

                <section class="employees">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="box-container col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="employee-box">
                          <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                          <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                          <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                          <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                          <div class="extra-info">
                            <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                            <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                            <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                            <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                            <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                            <h3>Email</h3>
                            <h5>cgomez@anticipa.com</h5>
                            <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                            <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                          </div>                          
                          <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="box-container col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="employee-box">
                          <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                          <h3>Raúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda Raúl García BoledaRaúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda Raúl García BoledaRaúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                          <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                          <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                          <div class="extra-info">
                            <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                            <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                            <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                            <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                            <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                            <h3>Email</h3>
                            cgomez@anticipa.com
                            <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                            <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                          </div>                          
                          <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="box-container col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="employee-box">
                          <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                          <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                          <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                          <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                          <div class="extra-info">
                            <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                            <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                            <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                            <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                            <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                            <h3>Email</h3>
                            cgomez@anticipa.com
                            <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                            <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                          </div>                          
                          <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="box-container col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="employee-box">
                          <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                          <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                          <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                          <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                          <div class="extra-info">
                            <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                            <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                            <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                            <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                            <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                            <h3>Email</h3>
                            cgomez@anticipa.com
                            <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                            <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                          </div>                          
                          <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>         
                    </div>    
                </section>
                <section class="employees">
                  <div class="row">                      
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                      <div class="employee-box">
                        <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                        <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                        <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                        <div class="extra-info">
                          <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                          <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                          <h3>Email</h3>
                          cgomez@anticipa.com
                          <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                          <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                        </div>                          
                        <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                      <div class="employee-box">
                        <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                        <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                        <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                        <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                        <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                        <div class="extra-info">
                          <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                          <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                          <h3>Email</h3>
                          cgomez@anticipa.com
                          <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                          <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                        </div>                          
                        <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                      <div class="employee-box">
                        <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                        <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                        <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                        <div class="extra-info">
                          <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                          <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                          <h3>Email</h3>
                          cgomez@anticipa.com
                          <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                          <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                        </div>                          
                        <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                      <div class="employee-box">
                        <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                        <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                        <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                        <div class="extra-info">
                          <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                          <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                          <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                          <h3>Email</h3>
                          cgomez@anticipa.com
                          <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                          <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                        </div>                          
                        <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>                                    
                </section>                                                                                                
            </section>
```

Here's the SCSS:

```
/*Colors*/
$body-blue: #ebeff2;
$deep-blue: #013662;
$light-blue: #0160a2;
$off-blue: #91bfdf;
$secondary-blue: #003561;
$title-bg: #c5d8e8;
$white: #fff;

body {
  background-color: $body-blue;
  color: #999;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  font: 300 16px 'Asap-Regular', sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding:0;
}

@mixin article-box {
    background-color: $white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em rgba(0, 53, 97, 0.05);
    .date {
        font-size: 0.75em;
        text-transform: uppercase;          
    }
    p {
        color: #0060a1;
        font-size: 1em;
        line-height: normal;            
    }       
}

.box-container {
    position:relative;
    height:17em;
}
.employee-box {
@include article-box;
margin-bottom:1em;
padding:1em;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
h3,h4,h5 {
    line-height:.8em
}
h3 {
    color:$secondary-blue;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    font-weight: 700;   
}
.area {
    font-size: 0.875em;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.extra-info {
    display:none;
}   
.position {
    color: $secondary-blue;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.dropdown {
    background:url(../img/forms/down-arrow.png) no-repeat left 50%;
    color: #005fa0;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 2em;
    padding-left:1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
&.current {
    background-color:#0160a2;
    color:#9cc4e7;
    max-height:500px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    h3 {
        color: white;
    }
    h4 {
        color:#9cc4e7;
    }
    .dropdown {
        background:url(../img/forms/up-arrow.png) no-repeat left 50%;
        color: white;   
    }
    .extra-info {
        display:block;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does this work for you? If yes, I'll add as answer. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWJaKx

Comment: Thanks @SergChernata but unfortunately it doesn't work for my particular case. When you click on the link at the end of each box just the height of that box have to change overlapping whatever is below the box (like in the original behaviour) so the problem in your answer is that when i click on the link all the boxes of that row change their height also. Thanks for trying tho, is this actually possible to do ? im really frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as I can get it without resorting to JavaScript trickery.

```js
$('.main-menu ul li').click(function(e) {
    $('.main-menu ul li').not($(this)).removeClass('current');
     $(this).toggleClass('current');       
});
$('.employee-box .dropdown').click(function(e) {
    $('.employee-box .dropdown').not($(this)).closest('.employee-box').removeClass('current');
    $(this).closest('.employee-box').toggleClass('current');          
});
```

```css
/*Colors*/
.row {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  display: flex;
}

body {
  background-color: #ebeff2;
  color: #999;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font: 300 16px 'Asap-Regular', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.box-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 17em;
}

.employee-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em rgba(0, 53, 97, 0.05);
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  min-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.employee-box .date {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.employee-box p {
  color: #0060a1;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: normal;
}
.employee-box h3, .employee-box h4, .employee-box h5 {
  line-height: 0.8em;
}
.employee-box h3 {
  color: #003561;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.employee-box .area {
  font-size: 0.875em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.employee-box .extra-info {
  display: none;
}
.employee-box .position {
  color: #003561;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.employee-box .dropdown {
  background: url(../img/forms/down-arrow.png) no-repeat left 50%;
  color: #005fa0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.employee-box.current {
  background-color: #0160a2;
  color: #9cc4e7;
  max-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.employee-box.current h3 {
  color: white;
}
.employee-box.current h4 {
  color: #9cc4e7;
}
.employee-box.current .dropdown {
  background: url(../img/forms/up-arrow.png) no-repeat left 50%;
  color: white;
}
.employee-box.current .extra-info {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="content col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1">
           
                    <section class="employees">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="box-container col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="employee-box">
                              <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                              <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                              <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                              <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                              <div class="extra-info">
                                <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                                <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                                <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                                <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                                <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                                <h3>Email</h3>
                                <h5>cgomez@anticipa.com</h5>
                                <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                                <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                              </div>                          
                              <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="box-container col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="employee-box">
                              <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                              <h3>Raúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda Raúl García BoledaRaúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda Raúl García BoledaRaúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                              <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                              <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                              <div class="extra-info">
                                <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                                <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                                <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                                <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                                <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                                <h3>Email</h3>
                                cgomez@anticipa.com
                                <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                                <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                              </div>                          
                              <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="box-container col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="employee-box">
                              <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                              <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                              <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                              <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                              <div class="extra-info">
                                <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                                <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                                <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                                <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                                <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                                <h3>Email</h3>
                                cgomez@anticipa.com
                                <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                                <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                              </div>                          
                              <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="box-container col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="employee-box">
                              <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                              <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                              <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                              <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                              <div class="extra-info">
                                <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                                <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                                <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                                <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                                <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                                <h3>Email</h3>
                                cgomez@anticipa.com
                                <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                                <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                              </div>                          
                              <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>         
                        </div>    
                    </section>
                    <section class="employees">
                      <div class="row">                      
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="employee-box">
                            <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                            <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                            <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                            <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                            <div class="extra-info">
                              <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                              <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                              <h3>Email</h3>
                              cgomez@anticipa.com
                              <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                              <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                            </div>                          
                            <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="employee-box">
                            <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                            <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                            <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                            <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                            <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                            <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                            <div class="extra-info">
                              <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                              <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                              <h3>Email</h3>
                              cgomez@anticipa.com
                              <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                              <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                            </div>                          
                            <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="employee-box">
                            <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                            <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                            <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                            <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                            <div class="extra-info">
                              <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                              <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                              <h3>Email</h3>
                              cgomez@anticipa.com
                              <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                              <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                            </div>                          
                            <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="employee-box">
                            <img src="assets/img/employees/avatar-employee.png" alt="">
                            <h3>Raúl García Boleda</h3>
                            <h4 class="position">Asset Manager</h4>
                            <h5 class="area">Recovery</h5>
                            <div class="extra-info">
                              <h3>Teléfonos</h3>
                              <h5 class="area">M. corto: 20 453 7621</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Móvil: 20 453 7620</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Ext.: 20 750 9441</h5>
                              <h5 class="area">Fijo: 20 750 9442</h5>
                              <h3>Email</h3>
                              cgomez@anticipa.com
                              <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                              <h5 class="area">Planta 2, Área 5</h5>
                            </div>                          
                            <span class="dropdown">más información</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>                                    
                    </section>                                                                                                
                </section>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZbxOe